# MySQL server has gone away error with Pylons, SQLAlchemy, Apache

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pylons

sorry if this is addressed, but i'm running

```
apache2 
SQLAlchemy 0.5.8 
Pylons 1.0 
Python 2.5.2
```

and on a simple page (just retrieve data from DB), I get: 
Error - : (OperationalError) (2006, 
'MySQL server has gone away') 
every few other requests, not after a long time as other posts I've searched 
for.  I still added

```
sqlalchemy.pool_recycle = 1800
```

but that did not fix the issue.  After a fresh apache restart, every 5th or 
6th requests gets a 500 from the above error, so its not a result of a long time out.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to increase max_allowed_packet configuration parameter value in you MySQL config.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

For example:

```
max_allowed_packet=128M
```